# How to simulate no browser installed under Windows

Tags: windows, browser, default-programs

In a python program running under windows I used the `os.startfile()` function to open `something.html` file.

I now wanted to test the edge case of having no browser installed.

How do I simulate this case under Windows without uninstalling all browsers?
I already tried to remove the default programs connection to html files but windows doesn't like that and doesn't let me do it.

Comment: For example, how about using a Windows Server with minimal functionality that does not have the desktop function installed?

Comment: You could just change extension of your `something.html` file to one not registered within a system.

Comment: @montonero that's a very simple and obvious answer... thank you.